# Cardinality of a set of functions

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A=\{f: \mathbb N \to \{0,1\} : |f^{-1}\{0\}|<\infty\}$. Calculate the cardinal of $A$.

The attempt at a solution:

It's clear that the set $A$ can be seen as the sequences of natural numbers of ones and zeros with finite terms that are $0$. Now, comparing $A$ to this set of sequences hasn´t help me up to now. The other thing I know is that $|A|\leq |\{f: \mathbb N \to \{0,1\}\}|=2^{\aleph_0}=c$

Could anyone help me with any hint or suggestions to find the cardinal of $A$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT:** Note that every function is fully determined by $f^{-1}(0)$. If that set is required to be finite, how many finite subsets are of $\Bbb N$?

Comment: Aaaall right: the cardinal of $\mathcal P_{<\infty}(\mathbb N)=\aleph_0$. I can define a bijective function $g$ from $\mathcal P_{<\infty}(\mathbb N)$ to $A$ as follows: $g(B)= f:\mathbb N \to \{0,1\}$ such that $f(n)=0$ if $n \in B$, $f(n)=1$ otherwise. I'll check for bijectivity and ask again if I have problems with that. Thanks very much!

Comment: By the way, this proves $|A|=\aleph_0$

Comment: Yes, yes it does. I was happy to help!